# Ar core support for huawei nova 5t

Tags: arcore, smartphone, huawei-developers

Huawei nova 5t doesn’t have an ar core support. How can I be able to add or install it in my device even though it is unsupported? I already tried downloading aPk for google ar core support but it doesn’t work in my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AR core requires certain hardware to be present on the phone you would want to use it on. If your phone does not have the required hardware, it will not be possible to install nor use it if you were able to install it.

[Here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/introduction-0000001050130900#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050130900__section12431159199) you can find a list of all the AR compatible HUAWEI and HONOR phones.